# Can I non-interactively send keyboard commands to a virtualbox image?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am experimenting with VirtualBox-hosted server images.

I have a snapshot of an installed Linux OS which is ready to be configured.

On the host OS (also Linux) I would like to be able to create and configure a new server image non-interactively with a shell script.

At the moment, the manual workflow is:

1. In VirtualBox, clone the virgin image.
2. Start the guest virtual machine and log in with the default username/password (Linux, non-graphical)
3. On the guest, run `configure-me.sh some_argument`
4. On the guest, change the root password.
5. On the guest, log out but keep the machine running.
6. On the host, applications can now use the guest's services.

Can I automate all of this from the host? (Yes, this procedure will be repeated quite often.) The key requirement seems to be

- wait for the guest to finish booting,
- send fake keypresses to the guest, and trust that the result is as expected (we can assume the pre-written configuration scripts are reliable).

Can VirtualBox do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a keystroke from the host to a guest in Virtualbox with VBoxManage with the command [controlvm](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm).

```
VBoxManage controlvm name_of_your_vm keyboardputscancode <hex> [<hex> ...]
```

You would need to find out all the scancodes for your commands.

Another way would be to run a script directly via the [guestcontrol](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol) option:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol name_of_your_vm run /location/of/your/script --username user --password password
```

That will login as the given user and execute your script.

Comment: I actually couldn't get this to work straight away, I gave up because my own solution has other advantages, but this is probably the way forwards for most people.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which is not VirtualBox-specific is to launch a TCP/IP server from `/sbin/ifup-local` which receives commands from elsewhere.

`ifup-local` will be triggered when the network interface comes up.